# Is it possible to measure rendering time in webgl using gl.finish()?

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl

I am trying to measure the time it takes for an image in webgl to load.

I was thinking about using gl.finish() to get a timestamp before and after the image has loaded and subtracting the two to get an accurate measurement, however I couldn't find a good example for this kind of usage.

Is this sort of thing possible, and if so can someone provide a sample code?

Comment: You have the general idea, so do that... This is how you get a timestamp in Javascript `new Date().getTime();`

Comment: related question... is this the mechanism (gl.finish) used by threejs or other frameworks & examples to show FPS?

Comment: you're better of using a profiler since some implementations ignore those calls

Comment: If you're trying to measure FPS see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432804/recording-fps-in-webgl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it is not.

In fact in Chrome `gl.finish` is just a `gl.flush`. [See the code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/modules/webgl/WebGLRenderingContextBase.cpp) and search for "::finish".

Because Chrome is multi-process and actually implements security in depth the actual GL calls are issued in another process from your JavaScript so even if Chrome did call `gl.finish` it would happen in another process and from the POV of JavaScript would not be accurate for timing in any way shape or form. Firefox is apparently in the process of doing something similar for similar reasons.

Even outside of Chrome, every driver handles `gl.finish` differently. Using `gl.finish` for timing is not useful information because it's not representative of actual speed since it includes stalling the GPU pipeline. In other words, timing with `gl.finish` includes lots of overhead that wouldn't happen in real use and so is not an accurate measurement of how fast something would execute normal circumstances.

There are GL extensions on some GPUs to get timing info. Unfortunately they (a) are not available in WebGL and (b) will not likely ever be as they are not portable as they can't really work on tiled GPUs like those found in many mobile phones.

Instead of asking how to time GL calls what specifically are you trying to achieve by timing them? Maybe people can suggest a solution to that.

Comment: I'm actually just interested in the timing as I am trying to fingerprint a client according to rendering time. Is there no other solution for timing webgl events?

Comment: Maybe consider timing calls between requestAnimationFrame events. If the time is too larger then draw less. Sorry I don't know of a good example though.

Answer (score 9):

It is now possible to time WebGL2 executions with the `EXT_disjoint_timer_query_webgl2` extension.

```
const ext = gl.getExtension('EXT_disjoint_timer_query_webgl2');
const query = gl.createQuery();
gl.beginQuery(ext.TIME_ELAPSED_EXT, query);
/* gl.draw*, etc */
gl.endQuery(ext.TIME_ELAPSED_EXT);
```

Then sometime later, you can get the elapsed time for your query:

```
const available = this.gl.getQueryParameter(query, this.gl.QUERY_RESULT_AVAILABLE);
if (available) {
    const elapsedNanos = gl.getQueryParameter(query, gl.QUERY_RESULT);
}
```

A couple things to be aware of:

- only one timing query may be in progress at once.
- results may become available asynchronously. If you have more than one call to time per frame, you may consider using a query pool.

Answer (score -7):

Being client based, WebGL event timings depend on the current loading of the client machine (CPU loading), GPU loading, and the implementation of the client itself. One way to get a very rough estimate, is to measure the round-trip latency from server to client using a `XmlHttpRequest` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest). By finding the delay from server measured time to local time, a possible measure of loading can be obtained.

Comment: How can you use an XmlHttpRequest to include the time it actually takes for the picture to load? (I saw something called onload() but not sure its relevant...). can you provide some sort of a sample code?